# Has LocateRegistry.createRegistry(int port) changed in java 1.7?

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

We have several server side components in our architecture. Each component uses JMX to expose various internal attributes. Initialization is done as follows:

```
try {       
        Registry registry = null;
        for(int i = _serverInfo.getJMXStartPort(); i <= _serverInfo.getJMXEndPort(); i++) {         
            try {
                registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(i);
                if(registry != null) {
                    _statusPort = i;
                    logger.info("Using JMX port: "+_statusPort);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                _statusPort++;
            }
        }                               

        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

        _abstractServiceController = new AbstractServiceController(this);
        ObjectName mbeanName = new ObjectName("MyServer:name=MyServer Service");

        mbs.registerMBean(_abstractServiceController, mbeanName);

        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:"+_statusPort+"/jmxrmi");
        JMXConnectorServer cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, System.getenv(), mbs);
        cs.start();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.error("Unable to register MBean with JMX");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I guess I have two questions.

1. Does this look right?
2. The bigger question is, while this runs fine on java 1.6 (each subsequent server on a host uses the next available port, since LocateRegistry.createRegistry(i) throws an exception if the port is unavailable), not so on 1.7. As a result, we get the following exception when the second server attempts to JMXConnectorServer.start(). Does anyone know if the behavior changed for createRegistry? If so, is there something else we should do?

   ```
   2013-02-07 15:34:28,451 INFO  [main] Using JMX port: 9500
   2013-02-07 15:34:28,929 ERROR [main] Unable to register MBean with JMX
   java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://:9500/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi]
           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServe.java:826)
   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:431)
   at com.theatre.services.framework.AbstractService.run(AbstractService.java:306)
   at com.theatre.services.reporttree.TreeServerImpl.run(TreeServerImpl.java:690)
   at com.theatre.services.framework.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:99)
   Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi]
   at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:139)
   at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.bind(GenericURLContext.java:226)
   at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:419)
   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:643)
   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:426)
   ... 3 more
   Caused by: java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi
   at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.bind(RegistryImpl.java:131)
   at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:390)
   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:248)
   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
   at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
   at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
   at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
   at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:137)
   ... 7 more
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> Does this look right?

- No. Creating a Registry can fail for several reasons, not just because the port is in use.
- `registry` cannot be null after `createRegistry()`, so testing for it is pointless.
- If you're trying to find a free port, just open *(and close)* a `ServerSocket()`. *Then* create the Registry on that port if it worked.

> The bigger question is, while this runs fine on java 1.6 (each subsequent server on a host uses the next available port, since LocateRegistry.createRegistry(i) throws an exception if the port is unavailable), not so on 1.7.

See above. Creating a Registry can also fail if there is already one running on that port, in any JDK. In earlier JDKs it would fail if there was one running on any port in the same JVM.